# Superscript and subscript points in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, geom-text

I would like to add sub/superscript to some letters/characters in a ggplot2 point plot. I know how to do this in the axes, but in this case, because they are special characters, I define a character vector before plotting:

```
IPA=(c("ph", "th", "kh", "p", "t", "k", "ts", "tsh", etc.))
```

I want to plot letter combinations such as p^[h] and ts^[h] for the points in the graph but this syntax doesn't work (nor p^{h} or p^h). See graphic.

```
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x, y, label=IPA))
p + geom_text(size = 5) +
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  scale_shape_manual(values = IPA)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the text to `plotmath` expressions and use `parse=TRUE` in `geom_text`. Below is an example with the built-in `mtcars` data frame. I've added your `IPA` values as a column to `mtcars` and then converted all of the instances of `h` to `[h]`, and all of the instances of `ts` to `t^s`, which are, respectively, the subscript and superscript expressions in `plotmath` (see`?plotmath` for more on expressions; there are also lots of Stackoverflow questions related to mathematical annotation in R plots). `parse=TRUE` causes `geom_text` to render the `h` as a subscript.

```
mtcars$IPA = gsub("h", "[h]", IPA)
mtcars$IPA = gsub("ts", "t^s", mtcars$IPA)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, label=IPA)) +
  geom_text(size=5, parse=TRUE) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! An alternative for anyone with a similar problem is to simply paste in the special characters to your vector before plotting. To ensure proper encoding, this is probably the best bet. Thank yoU!

Comment: How would you do it inside geom_hline(aes(linetype = IPA))? It does not work.